# Algunas manzanas / Unas manzanas

Tags: uso-de-palabras

## Objective

Confirm the difference between 'Algunas' and 'unas' which both mean "some".

## Question

Please confirm if my understanding is correct.

"Algunas manzanas" is about the apples known to the speakers. For example if I am in a fruit shop and ask "Give me some apples", it is talking about the apples in front of me and the shop owner.

"Unas manzanas" is about apples in general. For example if I am at home and ask someone to go and buy apples in a supermarket, I would use "unos manzanas".

Is this correct?

## Update

According to [algunos vs. unos](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/algunos-vs-unos.1207763/) in Wordreference and RAE, 'Alguno' seems to emphasise 'NO ninguno'. Probably stressing that it is not none but there are some about something.

So if someone asks "Do you think no one objects?" and I think there should be some who will oppose, then I would be using 'alguno'.

Comment: Algunas manzanas. Unas manzanas. Manzana in Spanish is feminin.(La manzana / las manzanas)

Comment: Fixed uno > una, alguno > alguna

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, **algunos**(masculine plural) / **algunas**(femenine plural) are indefinite so that means that your talking about apples in general. And it would be related to **some**.

e.g.

> **Some** apples are red. **Some** apples are green.
> **Algunas** manzanas son rojas. **Algunas** manzanas son verdes.

But **unos**(masculine plural)/ **unas**(femenine plural) is more specific to the apples you are talking about. In this case you have to use **some of**

e.g.

> **Some of** these 50 apples are red.
> **Algunas** manzanas de éstas 50, son rojas.

But careful, in case of **uno/una** (singular) is also used as the indefinite article **a/an** in English .

e.g.

> There is **an** apple in my bag.
> Hay **una** manzana en mi bolsa.
>
> I want to eat **an** apple right now!
> ¡Quiero comer **una** manzana en este momento!

But careful again, **uno/una** is also in Spanish an expression of quantity. Used to count things and in this case is equal to **one**.

> **One** apple, two apples, three apples.....
> **Una** manzana, dos manzanas, tres manzanas....

And finally, Apples in spanish are related to the femenine sense, so you must use **una/unas/algunas**

e.g.

```
**Correct**
```

> Una manzana, unas manzanas, algunas manzanas.

```
**Incorrect**
```

> Uno manzana, unos manzans, algunos manzanas.

---

### **UDPATE**

**Alguno/alguna** (singular) is still indefinite but in contrast to **ninguno** (none) as you found on Internet. It depends on the context because **alguno/alguna** is used as an indefinite pronoun also. In this case you should use **someone/somebody/anyone**

e.g.

Imagine that you are talking to someone else and you are about to go hiking in a group. And you want to know if someone came...

> **Someone** came?
> ¿**Alguno** ha venido?   --> Careful, this is more common in Spain.
> ¿**Alguien** vino?  --> This has the same meaning. Used in Spain but it's more common in Latin America also. It's more natural for Latin Americans to say like this.

**alguien** is an indefinite pronoun. Used exclusively for people.

You can use **alguno/alguna** for your apples but it's still indefinite (but not as a pronoun). But in this case you wil use **any** commonly for questions.

> Is there **any** apple on the table?
> Hay **alguna** manzana sobre la mesa?

This is in order to know if there is at least one!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I suppose 'Alguno/alguna' is more specific? It is written that uno/una is more specific but the example is "Algunas manzanas de éstas 50, son rojas".

Comment: @monta  Look! I updated my answer. There is an UPDATE section. Hope it is useful!

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not a native Spanish speaker, I have never noticed a rhyme or reason to choosing `algunas` versus `unas`, other than it may be that `algunas` seems a tiny bit less broad than `unas`.